# How to change the title of Lorenz's curve plotted using "precintcon" R package?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the Lorenz’s curve of a precipitation series using `precintcon` R package like

**Loading the daily precipitation series**

```
library(precintcon)
data(daily)
```

**Plotting the Lorenz’s curve**

```
pplot.ci(daily, interval = 1)
```

[image]

By default, the plot title is `..1`. I want to change it by station name. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(precintcon)
data(daily)
pplot.ci(daily, interval = 1, legend = "Whatever your title is")
```

[image]